MS-Word: Cannot print customized specified page of the Cover Page
I am using MS Word 2016.
I have used [Insert] > [Insert Cover Page] to create a Cover Page.
I was trying to print the customized specified page of the Cover Page which is on page 1.
I used [File] > [Print] > [Customized Pages] and entered 1. However, it did not print out the Cover page, it printed page 2 instead.
The Cover Page can be printed successfully if I print the whole document without selecting the specified page. But sometimes, I don't want to print it all, which could be a waste of paper.

If you print select pages as PDF, will this issue persist? It's recommended to go to File > Options > Dispaly, make surethe box of "Update fields before printing" is ticked.

@Emily Hi. I have read a Q&A which was answered by you. And I have selected the box of "Update fields before printing", unfortunately, it didn't help. And actually, I printed the select pages as PDF for the test, since it didn't cost me papers.

A cover page inserted using the Word command will be numbered 0. The simplest method is likely to simply have the CP on the screen and print Current Page. For more on cover page numbering see https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Cover_Pages.  It is different in different versions of Word. Also, in recent versions, the CP is not counted in numbering the total number of pages.

@CharlesKenyon Thank you. From the article you introduced, "Page numbers can get tricky with Cover Pages." It would make more sense if the total page number did not count the cover page. Would you consider making an answer based on your information? I could mark it as the answer.

Thank you. Done.

A cover page inserted using the Word command will be numbered 0.
The simplest method is likely to simply have the Cover Page on the screen and print Current Page. For more on cover page numbering see Cover Page Anomalies in my page on Sections. It is different in different versions of Word. Also, in recent versions, the Cover Page is not counted in numbering the total number of pages.

What happens to your page numbering (and headers/footers) when you
insert or remove a cover page is different depending on the Version of
Word you are using.
In Word 2007 the new cover page will be Page 1 of the document and
will be included in the NumPages field numbering (the "y" of the Page
X of Y structure). In later versions it is Page 0. In Word 2010 &
2016- 2024 (365), it is not included in the total page number
(NUMPAGES) field. In Word 2013 it is included in the NUMPAGES field.


tooltip for custom pages says:

Type page numbers and/or page ranges separated by commas counting from the start of the document or the section.

When you've multiple sections in the document, your page numbers are interpreted in the context of current section (section of active page).
Inserting a cover page introduces new section too.


update
I've tried to replicate your issue and interestingly it's the same for me too: asking for page 1 prints 2nd page of the document, however if I ask for page 0, then cover page is printed

In other words, make sure your cursor is on the cover page when you try to print page 1. Otherwise it will print the first page of the section you're in.

Hi. I tried to put my cursor on the cover page and enter 1 or p1s1 for printing. But they are still giving me page 2 on the tests. The cover page can be correctly printed if I use 'print current page'. And the status bar tells me the cover page is on Section:1 Page 1 of 2. Just don't know why custom print page 1 didn't work.

I have uploaded my test cover page on this link. It only contains the Cover Page and the Page 2. I am wondering if the layout settings of the Cover Page are wrong.

@Light indeed same behaviour for me too, however asking to print page 0 prints the cover page
